# psql how to create a column by applying a function to existing column

Tags: multiple-columns, psql

I have an existing column of geometry and I would like to create a new column with applying a function to that existing column. How does the syntax works? I got an error saying it(the existing column) cannot be referenced from this part of the query. Thanks

```
INSERT INTO folder(col1) VALUES (function(col1));
```

Answer (score 0):

to create a new column use [ADD COLUMN](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html), like here:

```
t=# alter table s95 add column new_col text;
ALTER TABLE
```

to set value by applying a function to existing column, use update:

```
t=# update s95 set new_col = concat('0'::text,i::text);
UPDATE 2
t=# select * from s95;
 i |  t   | new_col
---+------+---------
 3 | yoga | 03
 4 | yoga | 04
```

If your idea was to add column with default value base on other column, [it won't work](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html):

> The DEFAULT clause assigns a default data value for the column whose
>   column definition it appears within. The value is any variable-free
>   expression (subqueries and cross-references to other columns in the
>   current table are not allowed).